# ResourceNotFound when request the messages in the mail box

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I have corporate account that I logged in to Graph Explorer. When I try to fetch my profile, or manager details, it works. When I click in on "my mail", I get the following error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "f838caba-d769-4873-b7ba-80fd8e7016e4",
            "date": "2017-12-19T21:04:30"
        }
    }
}
```

If I switch to my private `@outlook.com` account everything works as it should. What could be the problem in this case ?

Comment: Do you have an Exchange Online mailbox provisioned to this account?

Comment: Hi,
i can not login with the account through the normal outlook web, it can be only via the outlook web server that in the company network, and mainly i want to access the api only inside the company, for Exchange online mailbox, how i can check if the mailbox  provisioned  ?

Comment: Tried to use the beta REST API, Getting the following
REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox.
so the corporate mail box need to wait for updates or the REST Api need to be updated ?

Answer (score 2):

You're receiving this error because the mailbox you're attempting to access is located on a local Exchange Server and isn't accessible to Microsoft Graph.

On-prem Exchange Servers are not supported by Microsoft Graph at this time. There is however a preview/beta available for Hybrid Deployments where you have a mix of Exchange On-Prem and Exchange Online mailboxes:

[Use REST APIs to access mailboxes in Exchange hybrid deployments (preview)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/hybrid_rest_support)